# The value for the useBean class attribute aruvi.tamil is invalid

Tags: java, jsp

I have searched in google but never found the solution.. I am using a JSP and JS file and one bean file.. I am setting Bean property in first JSP file but it shows the following file..

1. I have using default no argument constructor
2. Implemented Serializable
3. Bean, package and class bnames are as per the naming standards..!

Comment: we are not sitting in your computer to understand your question. Please post the relevant code

Comment: share ur code here buddy...

Comment: _"[whatever] are as per the naming standards"_ That doesn't matter to the compiler. It just helps you and others reading your code have it easier to do so. You code doesn't become correct just because you followed naming standards.